# How to replace default controls with custom buttons in Fancybox 2.1.5?

Tags: jquery, html, css, fancybox, fancybox-2

In Fancybox 2.1.5 I want to replace the default controls with my custom buttons
(new preloader + close/next/prev buttons on sprite).

I'm not sure how to adjust the css code properly. I tried to modify the CSS [as follows](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/7804559), but there's something wrong, the 'next' icon shows up in the top right corner instead of the 'close' button.

**You can see my code on [this gist](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/7804559).**

Answer (score 16, accepted):

No need to mess with the original CSS file, use the `tpl` API option instead like

```
$(".fancybox").fancybox({
    tpl: {
        closeBtn: '<a title="Close" class="fancybox-item fancybox-close myClose" href="javascript:;"></a>'
    }
});
```

**Notice** that I added the class `myClose` so I can set its own specific CSS properties, background image, etc. like

```
.myClose {
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    background: #ff0000;
}
```

See **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/UzsBV/)** just as an example.

Do the same for the prev/next icons. Check the [API documentation (search for tpl)](http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/#docs)

Comment: Thanks for the Tips. But this way looks much more complicated than just editing CSS file, which is small and simple enough. Fancybox plugin is used in Prestashop. I don't know where is tpl file needed for this. Altering prestashop template will be more complex, in my opinion. I adjusted jquery.fancybox.css file, it just works as required, example: http://codepad.org/NXqQL6a0. I'm not sure about some details here: `margin-top: -22px; margin-left: -22px; (line 88,89)` and `margin-top: -15px; (line 137)` - are these values linked with original buttons size or its independent from them?

Comment: @triwo the day prestashop decides to update fancybox, then you would need to customize the css file again. This why is not a good idea to mess with the original files (but it's up to you)... and `tpl` is not a file, is an option that you use in your custom fancybox initialization script to override what is in the CSS file without modifying it.

Comment: I will try custom fancybox initialization script, but now I just want to complete with CSS mods and to get answers on my question.

Comment: @triwo : well, I can assure you, you are taking the long way. Good luck. I will leave my answer in case it helps others.