# How to center a div horizontaly

Tags: html, image, center

I would like to know how to center horizontaly a div 
(check images when we resize the screen here : http://www.500milligrammes.com/juliep/code/ )

and if it's possible to have smaller arrows and close image when screen is under 700px for example

thanks a lot

Comment: You can align div content by text-align CSS property.

Comment: did you try my solution?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you easily horizontally center a <div> using CSS?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/618097/how-do-you-easily-horizontally-center-a-div-using-css)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit the demo container css to this to align everything center.

```
.demo {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 1024px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center; /*added code*/
}
```

As cybersoft states, adding`text-align: center` will work in this case.

As for fancy box, this answer should do the trick - https://stackoverflow.com/a/18556539/3194491

Comment: thank you @tonyedwardspz it works perfectly, for the icons that's baaaaad, i work on it, hope i'll find a solution ;)  


thanks again

Comment: No problems @furomlavi. I've updated the answer with a link to a solution for the icons. You basically need to define you own. Any chance you could accept the answer?

Comment: thanks man ;)  I check that and work on it now, i come back to you quickly ;D