# How to change close/prev/next button in fancybox?

Tags: jquery, css, fancybox

I want to change fancybox's buttons like below example.
please help!

[image]

Comment: You need to be more specific about what you are asking. Provide us the code you are working on so that someone could help you out. Like on what platforms you are working and the related code or links.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to target the button classes by inspecting them within the browser and then use CSS to customize the styles to your liking.

Try making an external CSS file and then target those button classes.

EDIT:  Check out this question here, it should give you a good idea of how to customize the buttons within FancyBox: [How to replace default controls with custom buttons in Fancybox 2.1.5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18551391/how-to-replace-default-controls-with-custom-buttons-in-fancybox-2-1-5)

Comment: Could you let me know the example codes as well please?

Comment: Please see my Edit from above.